# How Google know I using elite anonymous proxy

Tags: javascript, proxy, recaptcha

My bot use httpwebrequest to post to website that have reCaptcha.
If bot request without proxy, Google reCaptcha will MOST return a somehow readable image.
If bot request with anonymous proxy, and Google reCaptcha will ALL return double blob reCaptcha in which there are 2 black circle block which is extremely hard to recognized by even human.

So is that possible Google know a bot use elite anonymous proxy to request without any javascript running?

any possible way you can think? As I know, it is not possible because HTTP limit?

edit: if you access by vpn, google will not know it.

Comment: First of all, why are you hiding a bot behind a proxy for defeating captchas on other people's websites? That's bad behaviour.

Comment: i do not think your comment help anyone. it is against reCaptcha, because if you access reCaptcha from the same ip too often, google Recaptcha will be very complex and impossible to solved.

Comment: People install reCaptcha on their websites because they don't want bots to have access. The same reason you have locks on your door. If you can tell me that the owner of the website gave you permission to run a bot on his website, then I will answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

**Google actively looks out for proxies/socks servers & adds them to some kind of black list.
The proxy servers you are using are not new,
others have used them for bots & other things long before you, that's why Google knows when you are hitting the reCaptcha with a proxy.

As for VPN services
 Google knows about them as well,

the only VPN that Google would not know about is a VPN that you setup on a server that you own or a friend owns but after time of doing bad things Google will flag that IP as well.
When will you n00bs learn that Google is the all seeing eye, that knows all.

Your options are:

.1 make a new proxy servers (one way or another) who's IP is not flagged.

.2 use hacked WiFi or use Free WiFi around your area.

.3 be carful when doing this but use your own IP address until Google flags it & then when they do flag it change your ISP IP by using your router mac address spoofer. (Note most ISP-routers will not have "mac address spoofer" most store bought router will have it)

Unplug your cable modem, set a new mac address on the WAN side of your router & then plugin your cable modem & you will have a new IP but your ISP may get pissed if you do it too many times.

I sure hope your not spamming websites, I'm not for spamming peoples websites. I use bots to brute force logins just to say I got in but that's it ;)**

Comment: This sought of reads like a rant. And brute forcing logins, even if its just to say hi, is most likely illegal?